# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, join, next.js, typeerror

[TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8AzK.jpg)

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function PostAll() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { all } = router.query;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Post: {all.join("/")}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```sh
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 32 ms (176 modules)
error - pages/post/[...all].js (9:21) @ PostAll
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')
   7 |   return (
   8 |     <div>
>  9 |       <h1>Post: {all.join("/")}</h1>
     |                     ^
  10 |     </div>
  11 |   );
  12 | }
```

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.0.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
}
```

I am a very beginner and I am learning by watching online lectures. I can't quite figure out why I'm getting an error in this short code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`router.query` by default is an empty object`{}`, so after `const { all } = router.query;`, `all` is `undefined`. And you can't call `join` on `undefined`, as the error is telling you. The real problem is OP is navigating to "localhost:3000/post/hello/world" but still getting a null pointer exception. The reason for that is the component pre-rendered with an empty object and then rendered again with the array. This behavior is in the documentation linked below. "It[query] will be an empty object during prerendering if the page doesn't have data fetching requirements." So what OP needs is just a null check.

Documentation for the `router` is [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object)

```js
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Post: {all && all.join("/")}</h1>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: The purpose is to print "Post: hello/world" in "http://localhost:3000/post/hello/world", but when I print "all" to the console, "undefined" and "[hello, world]" are printed in the console. But it outputs as "Post: helloworld", where "all" is used like a "string".

Comment: What do you mean by "when I print "all" to the console, "undefined" and "[hello, world]" are printed in the console"? What is the exact value that gets printed out?

Comment: ``` lang-js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function PostAll() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { all } = router.query;
  console.log(all);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Post: {Array.isArray(all) ? all.join("/") : all}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```
After inputting like this, when I see the console log at "http://localhost:3000/post/hello/world", two logs, undefined and ["hello", "world"], are printed on the console.

Comment: Please read this part of the documentation: "It[`query`] will be an empty object during prerendering if the page doesn't have data fetching requirements." The component probably pre-rendered with an empty object and then rendered again with the array. So what you need here is a null check. I updated the answer with one way to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my first question, so I asked a question while searching for how to ask, and your kind answer was very helpful.